# Private Message Using JQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I am currently working on a Chat Application and ran into a slight hiccup, I want a message that is addressed to a user to only be visible to the user and the sender.

```
    <script>
  //PRIVATE MESSAGE
  var username = '<?=$_SESSION['username'];?>'.toUpperCase();
  $('#chatbox').children('.msgln').each(function(){
    var msgln = $(this);
    $$select = msgln.find('.messagelinebox');
    $message = $$select.text();
    if($message.indexOf('@') !== -1){
      var $product = $message.substr($message.indexOf("@") + 1);
      $$product = $product.substring(0,7).toUpperCase();
      var receiver = $$product;
      if(username = receiver){
        $(this).show();
      }else if(receiver = username){
        $(this).show();
      }else if(receiver != username){
        $(this).hide();
      }else{
        $(this).show();
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Filtering messages at the client side is a bad idea. The same message feed will be available to all the users, who will be able to read everything simply by overriding your CSS settings. You need to write a PHP script that generates a different message feed for each user (authenticated by means of a session cookie or something similar).

Comment: Yes but this is simply an assignment so it doesn't really matter, do you have any advice as to how to make it work?

Comment: Even in an assignment you should be aiming for the best code you possibly can. If you've made an error and it's been pointed out, the wrong thing to do is say "it's an assignment so it doesn't matter". You should at least acknowledge that it's wrong and think about how you could fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by everyone, you're going about things the wrong way.

However, there are some serious problems with your `if()` statement. This code:

```
if(username = receiver) {
    /* code */
}
```

is exactly equivalent to the following:

```
username = receiver;
if(username) {
    /* code */
}
```

If you want to test if two things are equal, use `==`, not `=`. Also, if `a==b`, then there is no need to test for `b==a`. Your entire `if ... else` structure can be reduced to the following:

```
if (username == receiver) {
    $(this).show();
}
else {
    $(this).hide();
}
```

Your code only checks for messages that were sent to the current user. It doesn't check for messages sent *by* the current user. That's another thing you will have to fix.

But really, do this all on the server. Not in client-side Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not comprehensive. I would like to see the result of what you have done so far if at all the sample you gave works. And as a matter of fact, you need to sieve your codes (code structuring is important) so that I'll be able to help you.

file_name.php

```
<?php //your PHP codes here ?>
```

file_name.html

```
<html>Blah blah</html>
```

file_name.js

```
$(function(){
//your jquery...
})
```